# How to add and remove client fields in remedyforce

Tags: community, administration

Hope you all are doing well .

I got stuck into a major problem .

I want to add some new fields to client layout and remove those mandatory fields which is email ID, Client ID and last name.

My client wants 20 more fields which is to be added while creating new client.

i am attaching the layout .

I am struggling it for past one month
[image: remedyforce]
Can anybody help me out ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add  your custom fields in Client Layout in remedyforce .
Follow steps:-
Step 1:- Create your custom fields from Setup>Customize>Users>Fields>New User Custom Fields.

Step 2:- Go to Field set to add custom fields into Client(Field Set > Main Panel) .

Step 3:-Then go to Remedyforce Administrator> Application Setting > Form Assignment
               Form To Assign :- Client
               Assign your profile (e.g. ServiceDesk System Administrator ) and Save.

Step 4:- Check your Client layout.

Hope it will sort out your problem

Thanks,
Shubham Mittal
Vyom Labs Pvt. Ltd.